# Different kind of multi-dimensional arrays in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java-native-interface

I'm using Java 11 (+ IntelliJ IDE). My code retrieves a multi-dimensional array through JNI from a 3d-party C++ library.

My code looks something like below:

```
Object[][][] param1 = {{{"somevalue"}}};
Object[] param2 = param1
Object[][][] param3 = (Object[][][])param2; //OK
Object[][][] result1 = SomeNativeLibrary.someNativeCall(param1);
Object someResult = result1[0][0][4]; //OK
Object[] result2 = result1;
Object[][][] result3 = (Object[][][])result2;  //CastException
```

I can clearly see through my debugger that the structure of param1 and result1 are different (even though both are assumed to be three-dimensional arrays):

for param1:  `{Object[1][][]} -> {Object[1][]} -> {Object{1}}`
for result1: `{Object[1]}     -> {Object[1]}   -> {Object[4]}`

Even though casting from param2 to param3 works without problem, casting from result2 to result3 fails with

```
 "java.lang.CastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be case to class [[[Ljava.lang.Object" (notice the single square-bracket versus triple square-bracket before the "L").
```

The problem I'm facing is that I return result1 through some remoting framework. So I end up (on the client/calling-side of the remoting) with a one-dimensional array like above result2.

1）How can I transform back result2 into a Object[][][] array so that I more readily access data?
2）Why is casting from param2 to param3 working but not result2 to result3?

Comment: You're gonna need to go through it with a for loop, there's no way to just cast from a 1-dim array to a 2-dim array AFAIK.  There might be a utility method somewhere in the Java standard library if you look around for it, though.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Read the SO instructions before posting question.

Comment: @Joker: could you please provide some basic guidance on which part of the code-sample is misformatted ? That's a lot in advance for your patience.

Comment: There are no multi-dim arrays In Java. Just arrays that contain other objects. Such an object might be an array again, that again contains objects.

Comment: Multi dim array in java is an array of reference, in C++ it's like a single array whos index is [i+n*j] where n is the width of the array. My guess is use a single array, get n, and either loop on it to copy to array of array, or wrap in an object to compute the index [i+j*n]

Comment: So you don’t get an error at the line `Object[][][] result1 = SomeNativeLibrary.someNativeCall(param1);`? What is the signature of `someNativeCall`?

Answer (score -1):

Look up the documentation of `SomeNativeLibrary.someNativeCall(param1)`, and check what it actually returns. The CastException shows that it is declared as a one-dimensional array of objects in the class file, so you need to treat it as such.

If it was a multidimensional C++ array originally, then it is likely that it is represented as a one-dimensional array in Java, with element `(x,y,z)` at index `x*Y*Z + y*Z + z`, where `Y` is the dimension of the array in the y direction, and `Z` the dimension in the z direction. But check the documentation to be sure, and use it in that manner.

A multi-dimensional array in Java is not structured like that, but as a one-dimensional array of pointers to other arrays. So you cannot directly cast it to a multi-dimensional Java array.